# Copying Text with Transparent Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, copy-paste

The easiest way to explain my issue is by using the Youtube site to replicate it. I am testing this on Mac OS, using Google Chrome 98:

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Go to Youtube in Dark Mode (background is #181818) (it's easiest to see the effects in dark mode, but it should also work in light mode too but the background will be #f9f9f9)
2. Open up Developer Tools and paste the following into the console:

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = "100px";
div.style.top = "300px";
div.innerText = "This is a test";
div.style.setProperty("background-color", "transparent", "important");
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

3. Try copying the text and pasting into a Google Doc. A black background is seen.

My goal is to insert a div through JavaScript, such that when the text is copied and pasted, there is no black background. My suspicion is that since I'm setting the background to transparent, on copy, it is inheriting the page's background (since Youtube is setting the `html { background: #181818 !important}` within one of their script tags.

So instead of making the background transparent, if I try this: `div.style.setProperty("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.01)", "important");`, the black background seemingly disappears (even though it is technically still there). Is there any way to make the text truly transparent on paste for an inserted div in this situation?

I do want to keep all other text formatting other than the background, so intercepting copy from JavaScript would not be ideal, and I'm looking for a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar problem and have found that using pre instead of div is a workaround.

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
}

pre {
  font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
}
```

```html
<div>I want to copy text in <strong>div</strong> with styles such as <b>bold</b>, <i>italic</i>, <u>underline</u>, etc., except for the background color.</div>

<pre>I want to copy text in <strong>pre</strong> with styles such as <b>bold</b>, <i>italic</i>, <u>underline</u>, etc., except for the background color.</pre>
```

I don't know why this works.

Surprisingly, copying a portion of the text in the div in the snippet above includes the background color, whereas selecting and copying the entire text in the div does not include the background color.
Does the selection no longer include the background color when it touches the pre?

This could be a Chromium-specific behavior. (I have not tested this in Safari or Firefox.)
I would like an explanation from someone who knows more about this.

Hope this helps.